# How to display a custom YAxis in recharts?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

How to display this array of objects and a custom YAxis in recharts?
I would like to see 1 separate line per object, how can I do that?

I'm not able to see the lines in the chart neither the custom YAxis...

```
  let newArr = [
    { at: 1618799105371, metric: 'Patrick', unit: 'kg', value: 90 },
    { at: 1618799105371, metric: 't-shirt', unit: 'pz', value: 11.99 },
    { at: 1618799105371, metric: 'waterTemp', unit: 'F', value: 24.39 },
  ];


return (
    <ResponsiveContainer width='100%' height={500}>
      <AreaChart data={arrayN}>
        <Area dataKey="value" />
        <XAxis dataKey="at" />
        <YAxis dataKey="unit" />
      </AreaChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
```

Expected output:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO67A.png)

Comment: Can you provide an image etc. that shows what kind of output you want to see?

Comment: Sure, please see imaged attached in the post, @AhmetEmreKılınç

Answer (score 1):

So you're looking to add lines and a YAxis?
For the lines you need to add the "Line" component

```
<Line type="monotone" dataKey="pv" stroke="#8884d8" />
<Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#82ca9d" />
```

You could try to map your "newArr" and create its own Line forEach.

For the question with the YAxis maybe look at [this](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/174).
Or look at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/line-chart-double-y-axes-4j73x?file=/src/App.tsx) if you scroll down and change "orientation" on the YAxis to "left" it gives the result you are looking for.